# Find by key and replace the value in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit new with javascript. Is there a way to find all `icon` and get their value and then replace their values with a new one?

I need to replace all of fa/FaCopy with `fcb/FcbCopy` in the json payload below. Any libraries or functions you can share?

```json
[
  {
    "section": "feature-list",
    "data": {
      "title": "Title here",
      "body": "body here",
      "features": [
        {
          "title": "Title here 1",
          "image": "body here",
          "icon": "fa/FaCopy"
        },
        {
          "title": "Title here 2",
          "image": "body here",
          "icon": "fa/FaCopy"
        },
        {
          "title": "Title here 3",
          "image": "body here",
          "icon": "fa/FaCopy"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "section": "title-list",
    "data": {
      "title": "Title here",
      "titles": {
        "list": [
          {
            "title": "Title here 1",
            "icon": "fa/FaCopy"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title here 2",
            "icon": "fa/FaCopy"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title here 3",
            "icon": "fa/FaCopy"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If your data had the same keys, you could forEach (this will change the original array) through the larger array and then forEach through the smaller array - 

    nameOfLargeArray.forEach(item => data.titles.list.forEach(listItem => listItem.icon = "fcb/FcbCopy")

This wouldn't work as the code currently is, since in one object the array you need to change is at data.titles.list and the other is at data.features.

Answer (score 0):

This will be very customized solution and deeply depended on your data.
If your data type will not change and remain same then you could use/modify something like this.

```
// DATA = Your array
const result = DATA.map((list) => ({
  ...list,
  data: {
    ...list.data,
    features: list.data.features?.map((feature) => ({ 
       ...feature,
       icon: feature.icon === 'fa/FaCopy' ? 'fcb/FcbCopy' : feature.icon 
    })),
  },
}));

console.log(result); // your expected result
```

Comment: The payload is dynamic, so keys/objects in `data` can be different